# Exibir Toast em classe que não é da activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Gostaria de exibir um `Toast`quando o usuário fizer `logout`.

Tenho esta estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro de `ConexaoFirebase`, tenho um método chamado `logOut`:

```
public static void logOut() {
    firebaseAuth.signOut();
}
```

e dentro da classe `PerfilActivity`, tenho um método que chama o `logOut()`:

```
private void eventoClicks(){
    btnLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ConexaoFirebase.logOut();
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Gostaria que toda vez que fosse feito `logout`, fosse exibido um `Toast`, então tentei o seguinte:

Dentro de `ConexãoFirebase`, criei um método chamado `alert`:

```
private void alert(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

e dentro de `logOut` chamei o `alert` passando a mensagem que quero que seja exibida, mas meu código ficou com erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a maneira correta para fazer exibir a mensagem?

Sei que poderia fazer o `Toast` dentro de `CadastrarActivity`, mas gostaria de fazer dentro da classe `ConexaoFirebase`.

Comment: Passe o `context` para os métodos `logOut` e `alert`: Ex: `ConexaoFirebase.logOut(context);`. e também `alert(context, "Mensagem");`

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo melhor? ainda não manjo de programação.

Comment: A questão é que o `Toast` vai ser exibido numa `Activity` ainda que o ponto de partida no mesmo não seja uma `Activty`. Logo apenas tem de passar o contexto dessa `Activity` onde quer lançar o `Toast`

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void logout(Context ctx) {
    auth.signOut();
    alert(ctx, "...");
}

private void alert(Context ctx, String s) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

O método logout recebe o parâmetro `Context` e depois passa para o método alert que vai exibir o seu `Toast`. Basicamente, todo `Toast` vai necessitar de um `Context` para poder ser exibido.

`ConexaoFirebase.logout(getApplicationContext());`

Answer (score -2):

para criar um toast fora de qualquer activity ou seja em uma clase separada mas que vai ser chamada pela activity so basta usar na activity uma variavel publica do tipo context x:exemplo

basta chamar na clase
nome_da_activity act = new nome_da_activity();

toast.maketext(act.x, msg, toast.length_long).show();

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).